# Handle null returned from a WCF service on the client-side

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I have a `WCF` Service and I am using `AJAX` to call the service methods from my web application. My `AJAX` call is as below.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:56083/Service1.svc/Web/GetIntegrationById?id=' + value,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: true,
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);                    
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                console.log("Failed " + data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            }
        })
```

This call is being used to implement Search functionality. `WCF` service contains the below method that is being called above.

```
public Integration GetIntegrationById(string id)
{
    IntegrationList integrationList = new IntegrationList();
    Integration integration;
    integration = integrationList.CreateIntegrations().Where(i => id != null && i.IntegrationId == Convert.ToInt16(id)).FirstOrDefault();
    return integration;
}
```

`CreateIntegrations()` method given below.(Created for testing purposes)

```
public Integration[] CreateIntegrations()
    {
        List<Integration> integrationList = new List<Integration>()
        {
            new Integration() { IntegrationId=1,... },
            new Integration() { IntegrationId=2, ... },
            new Integration() { IntegrationId=3, ... },
            new Integration() { IntegrationId=4, ... },
            new Integration() { IntegrationId=5, ... }
        };
        Integrations = integrationList;
        return integrationList.ToArray();
    }
```

Now when I enter values between 1-5 in the search textbox I get the respective Integration object. However, when I enter something that is not in the list above, for example, id=8, as expected the value of integration is null which gets returned from the web method. This leads to a parser error on the client side as it is expecting a `JSON` value and receives null which it fails to parse. So I changed the last line to

```
return integration ?? new Integration();
```

This was done with the hope of receiving a non-null value on the client-side. However, this fails with the error below.

[image: GET http://localhost:56083/Service1.svc/Web/GetIntegrationById?id=8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET]

I might be doing ample of things wrong here but I need to know how to manage/handle null values when returned from the service method. If not how do I handle a scenario where a requested item is not present? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than returning the `Integration` class, return a [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) and also set the `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: @Sajal,Thanks for the reply.  Actually this is a mock service that I have created of another service that is being worked upon by another developer. And this service serves both web and windows applications so I cannot really do that.

Comment: You could try throwing an exception if `integration` is null and see how that is received on the client side.

Comment: @Sajal That would break on the server side. Does not reach the client. For it to reach the client it would have to be passed through [HttpResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) but as mentioned earlier I cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is when you are giving correct or expected input ,successful response is returned i.e integration variable holds  known value which is understood by js. But for the wrong input deserialization is failing since the return value from the service is null and thus failing.

Assuming  $('#id').val() in client side html holds your input id value.

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: 'http://localhost:56083/Service1.svc/Web/GetIntegrationById',
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#id').val() }),
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: true,
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);                    
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    console.log("Failed " + data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                }
            })
```

Since its a mock service,suggest you to create the class object of Integration and tweak appropriately.I am sure,if you call GetIntegrationById  method within .net application,it will fail since integration object will be null but since its a JS call,its failing silently in js console.

```
Integration integration=new Integration();
```

Comment: than you for the answer. Whatever you have mentioned here is something that I am already aware of. What I am looking for is an elegant way to handle it so that I do not get such ugly errors. And to this `Integration integration=new Integration();` , well I have done that too and it makes no difference. The end result is still null.

Comment: Try post method also.Havent you?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see how it should make a difference since my service method would still be returning null. Issue is not with the passing of the data but with receiving and handling a null value.